# Getting Random sequence of sentences returned by dialogflow chatbot integrated with telegram bot

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram-bot

I have created Telegram Bot using Dialogflow free account.
The Dialogflow bot is linked to Python Webhook which is hosted on my local system and exposed to dialogflow using ngrok service.

Few weeks back it was working fine but now I am getting random sequence of sentences in case there are 2-3 sentences returned during single slot filling request or during fulfillment request.
However sequence is correct in case I am testing this on Web UI of Dialogflow console but while on Telegram sequence is not followed.

Guys Please help as soon as possible.

I have already changed ngrok url from http to https url